# Unexpected token '=' in React Component

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

Am I missing a loader possibly? I thought we were supposed to be able to use these ES6 functions in component bodies to avoid having to do the `.bind(this)` syntax [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

```
    ERROR in ./client/admin-side/components/Form.jsx
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (15:17)

  14 | 
> 15 |     handleChange = (event) => {
     |                  ^
  16 |         this.setState({value: event.target.value})
  17 |     }
```

My .babelrc has the following:

```
{
    "presets": ["env", "react"],
    "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

and I am using `babel-loader` for js/jsx documents

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use `transform-class-properties plugin` to use class fields, You can install it like

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-class-properties
```

and use it as a plugin

```
{
    "presets": ["env", "react"],
    "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread", "transform-class-properties"]
}
```

`transform-object-rest-spread` is used for the rest spread syntax which is like

```
const {a, b, ...rest} = this.props
```

According to the **[documentation](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-public-fields)**:

> This presents two related proposals: `"class instance fields"` and
>   `"class static fields"`.
>
> `"Class instance fields"` describe properties intended to exist on
>   instances of a class (and may optionally include initializer
>   expressions for said properties).
>
> `"Class static fields"` are declarative properties that exist on the
>   class object itself (and may optionally include initializer
>   expressions for said properties).
>
> This proposal is currently at **Stage 2**.

You can also solve this by using preset stage-2 by installing

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-2
```

and using it like

```
{
    "presets": ["env", "react", "stage-2"],
    "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help today Shubham! XD trying to figure out this React thing!

Answer (score 0):

you cant add stage-0 preset

```
{
    "presets": ["env", "react", "stage-0"],
    "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

and dont forget run

```
yarn add babel-preset-stage-0
```