# Syntax Error : Missing class property transform on arrow function.

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I integrated react on laravel 5.6. Everything was working fine but after using a arrow function in a component it give me following error
[image]

Comment: here's the link of my web.config,js fle 
https://jsfiddle.net/qqdrm1cq/




and here 's the link of my package.json file
https://jsfiddle.net/uygaych5/

Comment: tried all the solution  from here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48801984/unexpected-token-in-react-component


but did not work