# React onClick causes compiling error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop

I have a piece of code as below:

```
for (let i = 0; i <= total; i++)
  leftButtons.push(<Button onClick={() => console.log(i)} key={`leftBtn_${i}`} color="primary">{i + 1}</Button>);
```

This will cause a compiling error and the error message as "Module parse failed: Unexpected token (36:23)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type."

If I remove console.log(i) or change it to do not use i in the onClick, it will pass the compile. I really confuse why I can not use i in the onClick.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve

Comment: Hi Muhaimin, thank you for your attention. What I want to achieve is not really important here. I can find a way to go around. But I just do not understand why this code will cause a compiling error. Why I can not use the variable i in the onClick.

Comment: Possibly its because you are using arrow functions for which you haven't configured babel. You could refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48801984/unexpected-token-in-react-component/48802029#48802029

Comment: Hi Shubham, thank you for your answer. But I did configure babel and I can use arrow functions just find in other places. If I change it to console.log(2), it will pass the compiling. So, the problem is using the variable i.

Comment: Could you make the variable i to be a string in the console.log

Comment: The problem is I can not pass any variable I define in the for loop to onClick no matter what kind of variable is. But I would like to know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. The let keyword just allows the variable i live in the for block. However, the onClick function will be used out of the for scope, which will cause the variable i does not exist at that time. However, the compiling error message is too wired.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
onClick={() => console.log(i)}
```

Try doing:

```
onClick={() => console.log(i).bind(this)}
```

IMHO, this happens because you are using arrow function syntax and because `let` is confined within for loop and without `bind` that console will behave as it belongs to the global/outer scope where your let variable `i` **does not** exists.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But it is not because binding this. I has already found the problem. Please see my post.

Comment: It should not relate to binding because the onClick function does not use this. And yes, I tried binding. It does work. But if I change for (let i ...) to for (var i ...), it works just fine.

Comment: @Kevin Yes, that's because `let` is confined within for loop and without `bind` that console will behave as it belongs to the global/outer scope where your let variable i **does not** exists.

Answer (score 0):

As I noticed you used `leftButtons` variables to push your buttons which is wrong approach. You already have `total` and you wanna print buttons for every single record.

You can easily accomplish that in `jsx`.

```
{
 for (let i = 0; i <= total; i++){
  <Button onClick={() => console.log(i)} key={`leftBtn_${i}`} color="primary">{i + 1}</Button>;
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ruhul, thank you for your answer. However, the total is just a number instead of an array. So, map will not work for this case.

Comment: @Kevin, you are right but did it solve your problem?

Comment: Ruhul, thank you for asking. I solved this by using the event.target.innerText to get the number I want. Finding this solution actually did not cost me too much time. But figure out why my original code does not work is the hard part. I just feel uncomfortable if I get some errors and I cannot understand. :)